# GoLang: create a function that accept an interface (I came from PHP)

Tags: php, go

In PHP I can create an interface

```
interface Hello {
    public function bar();
}
```

And some classes that implements it

```
final class Foo implements Hello {
    public function bar() {
        // do something
    }
}

final class Bar implements Hello {
    public function bar() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Then, I can also create a NewClass::bar() method that accept the interface.

```
final class NewClass {
    public function bar(Hello $hello) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

How can I do the same, in Golang?

```
type humanPlayer struct {
    name string
}

type botPlayer struct {
    name string
}
```

How can I realize same pattern in golang?

Comment: All this is explained very well in the Tout of Go http://tour.golang.org/, especially the "Methods and Interfaces". Instead of copy-pasting the tour info here or badly rephrasing it, I'd like to recommend you take the Tour.

Comment: Very good link. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Namer interface {
    Name() string
}

type humanPlayer struct {
    name string
}

func (h *humanPlayer) Name() string {
    return h.name
}

type botPlayer struct {
    name string
}

func (b *botPlayer) Name() string {
    return b.name
}

func sayName(n Namer) {
    fmt.Printf("Hello %s\n", n.Name())
}

func main() {
    human := &humanPlayer{
        name: "bob",
    }
    bot := &botPlayer{
        name: "tom",
    }
    sayName(human)
    sayName(bot)
}
```

Comment: Sure, this shows how to do it, but how about explaining what's going on?

In go you don't declare that a struct implements an interface, you just implement the interface: In this case the Namer interface applies to any struct which implements a Name() function which returns a string.

Comment: witch is the difference between declaration with `var human humanPlayer` and `human := &humanPlayer{}`?

Comment: @sensorario The former declares a variable of type `humanPlayer`. The latter declares one of type `*humanPlayer` and assigns to it `&humanPlayer{}`.

Comment: Uh, so in `var` case we pass value, in `&` case we pass reference? In PHP everything is a reference. Go looks like C: I am talking about pointers. I am falling in love with GO.